# String array and list comparison

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, comparison

I have a String array `userArray` that contains 123 and 456. I also have a `dbList` that contains 123, 456 and 555

```
userArray[] = {"123", "456"}
List<String> dbList  = ["123","456","555"]
```

I want to compare both  userArray and dblist using Java 8. Since 123 and 456 are matching both should be retained but 555 should be deleted. Only matching elements has to be stored.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
// we create a new List to hold the matches
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

// we iterate over the entries in the array and check, whether they are in the dbList
// when they are we add them to the result list. 
// This will only work if all entries in the user array are there only once
for(String s : userArray)
    if(dbList.contains(s))
        result.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  It converts the array to a list using streams and then uses the
retain all feature of `List` to remove the unwanted elements.  There are better ways to do it but you specifically implied you wanted a `streams` approach.

```
     String userArray[] = {"123", "456"};
     List<String> dbList  = new ArrayList<>(List.of("123","456","555"));


     dbList.retainAll(Arrays.stream(userArray).collect(Collectors.toList()));

     System.out.println(dbList);
```

Prints

```
[123, 456]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stream.filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

By *dblist using Java 8.* you mean Java 8 Stream? If so, you could do like this:

### Example

```
    String[] userArray = new String[]{"123","456"};
    List<String> dbList = Arrays.asList("123", "456", "555");

    List<String> matchedValues = Stream.of(userArray)
            .filter( userArrayValue -> dbList.contains(userArrayValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matchedValues.toArray()));
```

And you have the output:

```
[123, 456]
```

Explaining the code:

First we make a Strem of your `userArray`;

Then we filter using Stream#filter method;

So each value `userArrayValue` will be checked if exists in `dbList`;

If so, we collect it into a new List by calling Stream#collect

That's it.

### Edit

Accoring to user comment

> Actually i need to do this comparison and do update and inserts on DB.
>   If value exists in both i don't do anything. If not exists in dblist i
>   will have to insert it and if values exists in dblist and does not in
>   userArray i have delete it

#### Values present in dbList and not present in userArray

```
    String[] userArray = new String[]{"123","456"};
    List<String> userList = Arrays.asList(userArray);
    List<String> dbList = Arrays.asList("123", "456", "555");

    List<String> unMatchedValues = dbList.stream()
            .filter( userArrayValue -> !userList.contains(userArrayValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unMatchedValues.toArray()));
```

#### Output

```
[555]
```

#### Values present in userArray not present in dbList

```
    String[] userArray = new String[]{"123","456", "888"};
    List<String> dbList = Arrays.asList("123", "456");

    List<String> unMatchedValues = Stream.of(userArray)
            .filter( userArrayValue -> !dbList.contains(userArrayValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unMatchedValues.toArray()));
```

#### Output

```
[888]
```

Comment: What do you mea by 'is my master' ? And is this a problem based on the solution I gave you?

Comment: UserArray = [123,456,777] and dblist = [123,456,888]  i meant userArray will be master reference. Now when comparing i see 777 from userArray does not exist in dbList. But my result should be userArray_result = [123,456,777] and 888(dblist) should not be in list as it is not present in userArray[]

Comment: So, resultArray, in my example, matchedValues should have all userArray values even if the value is not present in dbList Array? If so, why compare with dbList ? I mean userArray is the final value anyway, why compare them?

Comment: Actually i need to do this comparison and do update and inserts on DB. If value exists in both i don't do anything. If not exists in dblist i will have to insert it and if values exists in dblist and does not in userArray i have delete it.